# Plotting a Heatmap with a Circular Colormap

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, matplotlib-basemap

I'm interested in plotting a heatmap similar to the attached one using Seaborn and Pyplot. Any suggestions about the circular colormap?

[(Li et al., 2018)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQNRC.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's the "CET_C1" colormap from [colorcet](https://colorcet.holoviz.org/user_guide/Continuous.html). Colorcet colormaps are compatible with both matplotlib and seaborn.

Comment: Thanks! I see that it works for the colormap, but what about the circular shape? I cannot find a reference for that in Colorcet.

Comment: Do you mean that the colorbar/legend is circular (or more accurately annular)? That's distinct from the colormap (the mapping from the number domain to a color value) and is something you'd have to hack together in matplotlib.